# make laravel homestead site public without using third party services

Tags: laravel, homestead

I want to access my laravel homestead site from anywhere in the world without using third party services.I would like to know how I can do that.please help me

Answer (score 0):

You might use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which is already part of Homestead, to make your site or APIs public.

I recommend deploying on [laravel forge](https://forge.laravel.com/) using the optimal package. It's quite affordable.

Or alternatively you might play with [laravel vapor](https://vapor.laravel.com/).